# Visual Studio unit tests not completing

Tags: visual-studio

A new colleague is unit testing using VS pro 2019#'s built-in unit test, as we all do.

With one solution (.sln) none of the unit tests complete when run from the Test Explorer, no matter whether Run or Debug is selected (on a side not, when the unit test file is open in the IDE, it is normally possible to right click within a  TEST_METHOD and either Run or Debug, but neither of these seem to work, although the status bar updates to say "0 run, 0 passed, 0 failed".

If we breakpoint the final line of a unit test, and debug it from the Test Explorer, then the breakpoint is hit - no asserts fail and no exceptions are thrown. However, if we Continue, the test never ends and the status in the Test Explorer is never updated.

Worth noting:

- if just copy the code to my machine, the tests run as expected (and pass)
- on my colleague's machine, a few new unit tests have been added, but even existing tests exhibit this behaviour
- I Exported my Config & Imported on me colleagues PC, which changed nothing
- other Solutions' unit tests run as expected on my colleague's machine, including new tests added to those solutions

any idea what is going wrong, and ow to fix it?

(I am loath to uninstall & reinstall VS, as we work from home and the process takes hours over WiFi + VPN)

Comment: Old question, but did you ever solve this ? I have the exact same situation right now. Unchanged code from friday will not run on monday.

Comment: It's hard to remember, but we ***did** get it working. 1) get a teammate to run the VS installer. From memory, it has options uninstall/install/modify/ more. Select More and Export configuration. Then you do the same & import. 2) if that doesn't work, then upvote VS. The issue only affected 1 of a team of 4,and one of those 2 things fixed it, although we can't remember which. Good luck. If you find a solution, please post it here to help others in future

Answer (score 1):

We had a very similiar situation recently, where the whole solution would compile and run fine, but none of the tests would complete. In Output->Tests the last message would be "Test started" and then nothing. Stepping through it would not change the behaviour, the debugger would just not complete a step somewhere in the test.

What did solve this for us (for now) was **disabling the adress sanitizer** for all projects int the solution:

```
Project Properties->C/C++->Enable Address Sanitizer = No
```

This is only a workaround, because we want that feature ofc. Waiting for a patch from MS for now.

Comment: `Stepping through it would not change the behaviour, the debugger would just not complete a step somewhere in the test`. We could step through, rogjtbto the final line of the test. Stepping further just did not complete the test